# Getting user email from Twitter using Satellizer

Tags: angularjs, node.js, oauth, twitter-oauth, satellizer

I can't figure out how can I get email address from twitter. I've been using this as example - https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples/server/node. I've also seen that it's possible to get email from twitter's oauth - https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Given that you have to go through all the hoops to get whitelisted by Twitter in order to access user's email, it is it not part of the example code. If you really need to get user's email, you may have to do that outside Satellizer's auth flow." - sahat (owner of satellizer)

Answer (score 0):

The example server doesn't appear to get the email in the twitter case.

And the documentation link explains how to request

> Requesting a user’s email address requires your application to be
>   whitelisted by Twitter. To request access, please use this form.
>
> Once whitelisted, the “Request email addresses from users” checkbox
>   will be available under your app permissions on apps.twitter.com.
>   Privacy Policy URL and Terms of Service URL fields will also be
>   available under settings which are required for email access. If
>   enabled, users will be informed via the oauth/authorize dialog that
>   your app can access their email address.